# How can I find unanswered questions with specific tags?

Tags: support, tag-search

It seems like this should be easy, but I'm not finding it anywhere.  I'd like to find e.g. "all unanswered with tag [jni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jni)"

Comment: E.g. like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=unanswered ? Inb4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jni?sort=unanswered

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/view-or-search-for-unanswered-questions-with-a-certain-tag

Comment: @Duncan , I think your first comment will be more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a simple thing to do.
[image]

As you can see in the image, first take unanswered questions and then scroll down to the Unanswered Tags, and just choose the tag that you want and you will get all the unanswered questions of the tag you select.

If the tag is not in the Unanswered tags, then add that tag as one of your Favorite Tags and then select it after choosing Unanswered like I told before.

Hope this helps you......

**UPDATE**

Since the unanswered tags section got removed, I'm updating my answer to the new method.

[image]
Take unanswered section, then take filter. There you get the option to set filter the questions with available options.

Comment: Only works for popular tags

Comment: @Duncan , thanks for notifying. I edited my post ,  will this do ?

Comment: Thanks I'm marking this as answer because it actually is a different and better answer than found int eh duplicate

Comment: **Unanswered Tags** seem to exist no more. There is only watched and ignored tags available currently.

Comment: @Matt Indeed. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @jperl - unfortunately, no.

Comment: @jperl, I've updated the answer to the new method.