# The 'unanswered' tab has multiple answered questions

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

Recently I have reached to the ***unanswered*** tab on Stack Overflow to view and help those who have not got an answer.

But at the end of the page number I see that there are many questions which have more than one answer with an accepted mark. See here:

[image]

So I want to know: Is it a bug or there is any other reason to have such questions in ***unanswered*** tab?

If this is a bug then please fix it.

Comment: That's been around for a long time now ( I noticed it when I first joined SO  around 3 months ago )

Comment: @ArunA.S And till now it is there? amazing ...

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232138/248731, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4146/248731

Comment: @jonrsharpe the link you have posted is not relevant as these question says the question having answer without upvote is consider as new but here is upvoted and accepted question.

Comment: @Misspoo it's the **answers** that must have upvotes.

Comment: None of those have been accepted, in case that wasn't clear. It's gold text within the answer count that signifies acceptance, not the green background.

Comment: I totally agree this is confusing though and seems like a bug, one of the reasons for this to stop questions which have a wrong answer from falling out of the queue to get a right answer. If every question which has an answer was pulled from that list it would result in many questions never getting a good answer. Though the UI could do with some cleaning up on this front to make it less confusing.

Comment: Definitely a design bug considering green on other sites mean answered. That's super confusing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Stack Overflow only considers questions that either have an answer with a positive score or an accepted answer as answered. So those questions you see are considered unanswered on Stack Overflow.

So, if you take the *Questions* tab and then take the *unanswered* sub-tab, the questions will also have answers as shown here:

[image]

But, there is a different category of questions without any answers. You can access them in the *unanswered* tab and then the no-answer's sub tab as shown in the image:

[image]

These questions will have no answers.

You can also read this question for another feature:

*[How can I find unanswered questions with specific tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288480/4516316)*

Comment: It's a bit confusing because the "Unanswered" tab and the "unanswered" sub-tab on the "Questions" tab have different semantics. (The latter is the same as the "no answers" sub-tab on the "Unanswered" tab.)

Comment: @TedHopp , it sure is, I actually found the no-answer's sub-tab in Unanswered Section by accident when I was answering a question related to this a month ago.

Comment: Or search on: `[tag] answers:0 closed:0 score:1`

Comment: There's a meta post somewhere talking about upcoming changes to these categories.  Can't seem to find it right now though.