# Why does the filter=need-answers do not work on page 2?

Tags: support, bug, new-nav, unanswered-questions

Earlier today I clicked on the `unanswered` link for the `àndroid` tag. (the one in the picture below)

[image]

This redirect to the link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?filter=need-answers&sort=votes
```

First page looks ok (no accepted answer, sorted by vote), but when I clicked on second page which redirect to the link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?filter=need-answers&sort=votes&page=2
```

I get

[image]

which does not seem to be unanswered questions (just sorted by vote). You can get the same page using this link

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes&page=2
```

so the `filter=need-answers` seems to have some issues.

Is this a bug ?

(It looks like different from this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292013/the-unanswered-tab-has-multiple-answered-questions).)

Comment: Yes this is a duplicate. Did not found it before asking my question. Thanks