# Feedback: Filtering I want to select "Unanswered "AND something else at the same time - such as "Featured" or "Newest"

Tags: feature-request, search

This was for the Angular tag:

[image: Filter options]

I want to select *Unanswered* AND something else at the same time - such as *Featured* or *Newest*.

Vote up if you agree!

Also if I use the URL https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/angular?page=2&tab=newest, *why does it show answered questions?!*

[image: Showing answered question when requested unanswered]

Comment: hit the search bar on top, click "Advanced Search Tips", copy past "answers:0".

Comment: It looks like this will be possible with https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer, but I'm not sure when it will become available.

Comment: Your edit should be a new question honestly, but it is a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292013/the-unanswered-tab-has-multiple-answered-questions.  Essentially "unanswered" means no answers, or questions with unaccepted no score answers.

Comment: @psubsee2003 So semantically it should say unaccepted to be more precise than unanswered. That is confusing as heck. I want to see unanswered - per my definition - not the SO definition.

Comment: @JGFMK that wouldn't be accurate either as the question is considered "answered" if an answer gets an upvote regardless of the accepted/unaccepted status.  But consider it from this perspective - someone is searching for unanswered questions to answer.  Why filter our stuff that has received a few bad answers.  Until someone "thinks" there is a good answer, the question is still unanswered.  And upvotes are supposed to be a way to measure quality or usefulness of an answer

Comment: I guess the question then becomes why waste time if someone else has answered. Effective use of my time is the answer.  Scanning for questions nobody has yet replied to. That is far more important to me.

Comment: @JGFMK there used to be a "no answers" filter that was different than unanswered.  I don't use it so I don't remember if it still exists with all of the various UI changes over the years

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused by the term "unanswered" in SE context. As [psubsee2003 has commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380712/feedback-filtering-i-want-to-select-unanswered-and-something-else-at-the-same/380750#comment673869_380712), unanswered questions are questions without accepted or upvoted answers. The one you want is the "no answers" filter which is already available, but it's sorted by votes by default.

As [Drag and Drop commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380712/feedback-filtering-i-want-to-select-unanswered-and-something-else-at-the-same/380750#comment673825_380712), the workaround is to use `answers:0` keyword to show questions with 0 answers. For example: [`[angular] answers:0` (with 'newest' filter)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bangular%5d%20answers%3a0)

---

In the future though, as [grooveplex commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380712/feedback-filtering-i-want-to-select-unanswered-and-something-else-at-the-same#comment673826_380712), [Custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781) will replace the current questions tab. Currently, it's in the testing phase, including Stack Overflow.

While it's in testing phase, users need to opt-in from their [Site's Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/2821954), then tick the "Opt me in" for "Custom Question Lists".

When it's active, users can create a custom list, like [newest no-answers Angular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers) and save it for quick access.